# Tensorflow - convert python.framework.ops.Tensor to PNG Image

Tags: tensorflow

is it possible to convert `python.framework.ops.Tensor` to PNG image?

the op is: `Tensor("layer_1/Tahn:0", shape=(1, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
tf.image.encode_png(tf.cast((tf.reshape(..., [256, 256, 3]) + 1.) * 127.5), tf.uint8))
```

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.eye(256, batch_shape=[1])
bgr = tf.stack([data, data, data], axis = 3)
png = tf.image.encode_png(tf.cast((tf.reshape(bgr, [256, 256, 3]) + 1.) * 127.5, tf.uint8))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    png_data_ = sess.run(png)
    open("d:/temp.png", 'wb').write(png_data_)
```

Comment: call `sess.run(...)` with this Tensor, then you will get `np.ndarray` as result and you can use your preferred method for saving `np.ndarray`

Comment: I got an error:  `FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value generator/decoder_1/deconv/filter` and `[[Node: generator/decoder_1/deconv/filter/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@generator/decoder_1/deconv/filter"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](generator/decoder_1/deconv/filter)]]`

Comment: I got tensor without shape. `Tensor("generator/EncodePng:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`

Comment: Example added to answer

Comment: the code freeze at `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`. I use CPU mode

Comment: This example will work without this line, but you should sort out this problem.

Comment: when I run `encode_png` line I got empty shape -> `Tensor("generator/EncodePng:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`. is it possible?

Comment: ok. when I run your code on my data I get an error (the 3rd comment here).

Comment: Do you solve the problem of freezen `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`? Do you try to launch the code from my example? Is it work? The error does not relate to the export to png, it is another problem.

Comment: the problem wasn't solved yet. I'm trying to add it to `pix2pix.py` code